# i have prepared form api, now how to insert form values when i click submit button by using db_insert

Tags: forms

I have prepared a form using Drupal form API. Now how can I insert the form values when I click the submit button by using `db_insert()`?

```
$form['totp'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Title of the Programme'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#maxlength' => 250, 
    '#size' => 50,    
);

$form['pd'] = array(
    '#type' => 'radios',
    '#title' => t('Programme Day'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#options' => array(
        0 => 'One Day Programme',
        1 => 'Two or More Day Programmes'
    ),
);
```

The above values to be stored in MySQL table?

Answer (score 3):

You would need to add a custom form submit handler.

```
$form['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_custom_form_submit';
```

Then, in the function, use `$form_state['values']`;

```
function mymodule_custom_form_submit($form, $form_state){
    db_insert('yourtable')
        ->fields(array(
            'totp' => $form_state['values']['totp'], 
            'pd' => $form_state['values']['pd']
          ))
        ->execute();    
}
```

Comment: +1. If your form function is "my_custom_form", "my_custom_form_submit" will be called automatically so no need to add submit handler manually.